# elements matching mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb

my question is how I can translate into php the following js code from mongodb  :

> t.find( { group:3, 'x.a':2 }, { 'x.$':1 } ).toArray()[0].x.length,
>             "single object match (array length match)" );

You can find the whole js code at :

> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/83ec59844bdd629b2b32a9791a4e7a0e93516c02/jstests/elemMatchProjection.js

Basically what I care about is how can I translate into php toArray()[0].x.length ? I know php has count but I don't care about that. I have other advanced queries and all of them reduce to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation of `toArray()[0].x.length` would be:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(['group' => 3, 'x.a' => 2], ['x.$' => 1]);
$documents = iterator_to_array($cursor, false);
count($documents[0]['x']);
```

Alternatively, it would be easier to use [MongoCollection::findOne()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php) in the above example, since we're only working with the first result and ignoring any others. Rewritten:

```
$document = $collection->findOne(['group' => 3, 'x.a' => 2], ['x.$' => 1]);
count($document['x']);
```

I didn't follow what you mean by "I know php has count but I don't care about that." Unless you were referring to [MongoCollection::count()](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.count.php), the basic [count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) is necessary to calculate the length of the array in the returned document.

Comment: I know I can do it like that but this is the only possibility to do it? I though maybe there is something that is returning the exact array I want, just for performance. Or doesn't really affect the performance?

Comment: Field selection will still return everything within the context of the top-level document. You could theoretically use MongoDB to transform the results (e.g. [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) or server-side JS), but that wouldn't be anywhere near as efficient.